# filter an array of objects based on another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a list of subjects and need to filter it based on the filter selection

```
let subjects = [
    {
        "id": "course 1",
        "title": "course 1",
        "area": ["red"," blue"],
        "mode": "offline",
        "available": "full-time | part-time",
    },
    {
        "id": "course 2",
        "title": "course 3",
        "area": ["red"],
        "mode": "online",
        "available": "part-time",
    },
    {
        "id": "course 2",
        "title": "course 3",
        "area": ["blue", "green"],
        "mode": "offline",
        "available": "full-time | part-time",
    },
]
```

There are 3 filters(area, mode, available) where the user can select multiple options from each filter

For example, after user selection my filter object looks like (it can be empty if none of the options are chosen from filters, here I have not chosen any options from filter2)

```
let filters = { filter1: ["red", "green"], filter2: "" , filter3: ["full-time"]}
```

Expected output

Based on the filters selected, I need to display the subjects that has

1. `subjects.area` as red or green or both
2. `subjects.available` as full-time

```
let subjects = [
    {
        "id": "course 1",
        "title": "course 1",
        "area": ["red"," blue"],
        "mode": "offline",
        "available": "full-time | part-time",
    },
    {
        "id": "course 2",
        "title": "course 3",
        "area": ["blue", "green"],
        "mode": "offline",
        "available": "full-time | part-time",
    },
]
```

Things I tried

1. I tried using `filter()` and `includes`

```
const results = subjects.filter(function(s){
                  return s.includes(filters)
               )};
```

2. I tried converting the filter object to an array with the selected values eg;`let filters = ["red","green","full-time"]` and used `filter()` and `includes` , but no luck

Comment: why not use for `available` an array, too? why not use the keys of filter for the names of properties which they apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you habe an object with same named properties, you could take a dynamic approach, by converting all items to arrays and check against.

```js
const 
    subjects = [{ id: "course 1", title: "course 1", area: ["red"," blue"], mode: "offline", available: ["full-time", "part-time"] }, { id: "course 2", title: "course 3", area: ["red"], mode: "online", available: "part-time" }, { id: "course 2", title: "course 3", area: ["blue", "green"], mode: "offline", available: ["full-time", "part-time"] }],
    filters = { area: ["red", "green"], mode: "" , available: ["full-time"], foo: [], none: undefined },
    constraints = Object
        .entries(filters)
        .filter(([, v]) => v !== '' && v !== undefined && Array.isArray(v) && v.length)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, [].concat(v)]),
    result = subjects.filter(o => constraints.every(([key, value]) => []
        .concat(o[key])
        .some(v => value.includes(v))
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you !! This seems to be a dynamic approach.

Comment: I guess `v.slice()` is more obvious and efficient why to copy an array than `[].concat(v)`? Also why to copy arrays if the whole code is pure.

Comment: @silentmantra, `concat` works for arrays and non arrays and returns always an array.

Comment: @Nina Scholz , I was just checking it with various data, when the filters has values like undefined or [], it is returning empty result. I tried adding ```.filter(([, v]) => (v !== '') || (v !== undefined) || (v !== [])``` but still no luck. Could you please suggest what can be done here

Comment: you could check for the other values and filter the filters. please see edit. btw, you can not compare an array with another, becasue arrays are objects and they are only equal if they share the same object reference. for adding more than one condition to the filter function, it needs to be chained with logical AND, because all conditions have to be `true`.

Comment: Thank you once again for your time and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let subjects = [
    {
        "id": "course 1",
        "title": "course 1",
        "area": ["red"," blue"],
        "mode": "offline",
        "available": "full-time | part-time",
    },
    {
        "id": "course 2",
        "title": "course 3",
        "area": ["red"],
        "mode": "online",
        "available": "part-time",
    },
    {
        "id": "course 2",
        "title": "course 3",
        "area": ["blue", "green"],
        "mode": "offline",
        "available": "full-time | part-time",
    },
]

let filters = { filter1: ["red", "green"], filter2: "" , filter3: ["full-time"]}

const filtered = subjects.filter(
    subject => subject.area.some(area => filters.filter1.includes(area)) 
    && (!filters.filter2 || filters.filter2 === subject.mode) 
    && subject.available.split(/\s*\|\s*/g).some(available => filters.filter3.includes(available))
)


console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Thank you I tired this, but it is always not the case that filter 2 will be empty it can be filter 1 or 3 as well. I just added !filters for other 2 filters as well

Comment: @user3699344 yes, just adjust the filter to your needs and don't forget to upvote my answer or accept it with the check ;)

Comment: @user3699344 you need to check the array filters only if the could be `null` or missing (`undefined`). if they are an empty arrays - the filtering would work fine

Comment: Yes, I need to check for all the falsy values.